# Rookie: window.onresize needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a rookie when it comes to programming, so I really need your help here. I need to change some code to fulfil my needs and I can't seem to do it in a proper way. What I need right now, is to take this script and make it work when the $(window).width > 480 . Also, I need this script to run every time the user resizes the window.

I apologise for my silly question, but I'm just starting to learn the basics about Javascript and Jquery, and I can't seem to find the answer to this question this time.

Here is the code

```
      $(window).load(function(){
    (function($) {

      $.fn.eqHeights = function() {

          var el = $(this);
          if (el.length > 0 && !el.data('eqHeights')) {
              $(window).bind('resize.eqHeights', function() {
                  el.eqHeights();
              });
              el.data('eqHeights', true);
          }
          return el.each(function() {
              var curHighest = 0;
              $(this).children().each(function() {
                  var el = $(this),
                      elHeight = el.height('auto').height();
                  if (elHeight > curHighest) {
                      curHighest = elHeight;
                  }
              }).height(curHighest);
          });
      };

      $('.articles_container').eqHeights();

  }(jQuery));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute it on window resized, do this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   $('.articles_container').eqHeights();
}
```

Also, if you want to execute javascript upon media queries events, then use the sweet [**enquire.js**](http://wickynilliams.github.com/enquire.js/) javascript library.

Comment: Nelson, thank you so much for your quick reply! I also need the script the run ONLY when the stage width is bigger than 480 px. I want to come up with some sort of Javascript Media queries (if you can compare this two very different things).

Anyway, I tried to implement your suggestion but with no success. I'm a beginner, so I must be doing something wrong here...

Comment: The enquire.js library would be much helpful to you then, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The window has an `.innerWidth` property which I presume is still accessible through jQuery. so your code might be something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   if($(window).innerWidth < 480) return;
   $('.articles_container').eqHeights();
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, urbananimal! So, should I just replace [ $('.articles_container').eqHeights(); ] with the code you wrote there?

Comment: Yes. That should do it. I think.

Comment: Worth noting that I don't think this will work on earlier versions of IE think only >IE8